# Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:onClick' with parameter type lambda on android.widget.RelativeLayout

Tags: android

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<data>
    <variable name="user"
        type="com.daimler.user.persistence.User"/>
    <variable name="callback"
        type="com.daimler.user.ui.UserClickCallback"/>
</data>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/row_padding"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/row_padding"
    android:onClick="@{() -> callback.onUserClick(user)}">
```

---

```
public class UserClickCallback {

   public void onUserClick(User v) {

   }
}
```

I wrote code like this, it looks okay but it shows error:

> Error:(36, 28) Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:onClick'
>   with parameter type lambda on android.widget.RelativeLayout.

Anybody help ?

Answer (score 15):

Change this line . Hope this Help.

```
android:onClick="@{() -> callback.onUserClick(user)}">
```

To

```
android:onClick="@{(view) -> callback.onUserClick(user)}">
```

Comment: If this answer helps to solve your problem then accept this answer as right answer by right tick mark

Comment: I dont think this should be a correct answer. The above codes have same effect.

Comment: it should and does work regardless of whether there's a parameter in the lambda.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem.
I deleted the "`.gradle`" folder and clicked "`Rebuild Project`".

**It worked for me.**

Comment: I wish if I could upvote you 100 times. I had 50 errors, I could not find the exact one. After deleting .gradle, it pointed me to exact error.

Comment: same comment from above :D

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. The default binding adapter doesn't work so i added app:onclick binding:

```
@BindingAdapter({"app:onClick"})
public static void setOnClick(View view, View.OnClickListener clickListener) {
    view.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    view.setClickable(true);
}
```

Then i changed the xml like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:clickable="true"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/row_padding"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/row_padding"
app:onClick="@{() -> callback.onUserClick(user)}">
```

Comment: Yes, i can't find another solution for this so far.

Answer (score 0):

change "android:onClick" to "android:onClickListener", It works for me.