# Android onClick() on include view won't let binding

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mvvm, data-binding

I have a separate layout that I want to call `onClick` and update a field on callback

```xml
<include
    android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.changeItem(2)}"
    layout="@layout/item"
    app:attr="@{viewModel.title}"
    app:desc="@{viewModel.description}"
    app:active="@{viewModel.isSelected}"
/>
```

But it returns the following binding error:

> Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:onClick' with parameter
>   type lambda on com.X.databinding.ItemBinding.

But I can binding on other views

```
<TextView
    android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.changeItem(1)}"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47827685/cannot-find-the-setter-for-attribute-androidonclick-with-parameter-type-lambd)?

Comment: i did, it's working completely if set in textView or button and etc

Comment: I think the problem is solved here: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52898833/databinding-and-included-layouts-cannot-find-setter-attribute-for-onclick)

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest you is to call the onClick directly from code.

Setup an ID for your view in your .xml, then set something like this :

```
val item = findViewById(R.id.your_id) etc.
item.onClick { functionYouWantToCall() }
```

However, I do not know if this is possible to set an ID or an `onClickListener` on an `include` layout.
If you can not do it, simply put your include inside a `LinearLayout`, then set your `onClick` on it.

I used to set onClicks in the .xml too, but I think it is much more efficient to set it in the code.
Moreover, I do not know if you can set arguments in a function you call from the xml.